# DB2 jdbc connection error Connection refused. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I have a new DB2 server (v10.5.0.3), and I can connect to the database locally just fine.

When trying to connect from a remote server using JDBC I am getting the "Connection refused. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001" error. Based on information found here https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21403644 I have confirmed that

```
[db2inst1@db2 ~]$ db2set -all
[i] DB2COMM=TCPIP
[i] DB2AUTOSTART=YES
[g] DB2SYSTEM=db2.xxxx.com
[g] DB2INSTDEF=db2inst1
[g] DB2ADMINSERVER=xxxxxx
```

and

```
[db2inst1@db2 ~]$ db2 get database manager configuration | grep -i svce
 TCP/IP Service name                          (SVCENAME) = 50001
 SSL service name                         (SSL_SVCENAME) =
```

with these JDBC connection values

```
driver=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
url=jdbc:db2://db2.xxxxx.com:50001/TESTGEN
username=XXXXXXXX
password=XXXXXXX
```

I have verified that the firewall on the both servers have opened ports 50000 and 50001. I've run out of ideas, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a network error, not DB2. Use `netstat -ap | grep db2sysc` or similar on the server to verify that the instance is indeed listening on the port you think it does, and `telnet serverhost 50001` on the client to confirm that you can connect.

Comment: I'm not ruling out a network problem, but I'm still stumped. netstat shows db2 listening on 50001, and telnet dbserver 50001 results in a Connection Refused error, even from dbserver locally. Both servers are on the same sub-net and both have port 50001 open on the firewall. It seems as though db2 is refusing the connection.

Comment: If DB2 is refusing the connection there should be something in the db2diag.log. If it is not, then it is the network alone.

Comment: Can you just try to disable the firewall completely?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble... Its was caused by IPV6... 
The URL connection point to localhost, resolved as ::1 (the IPV6 address of localhost) and DB2 server doens't listing IPV6 protocol.

I resolved by modify the c:\windows\system32\driver\etc\host file : I uncomment the line 127.0.0.1 locahost to force ipv4 resolution name of locahost... and it's works.

I hope that helps. *(sorry for my English)*

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a network error. I'm not fully sure which fix was the most important but I made sure telnet was enabled and white listed the DB2 process in the RHEL firewall configuration.

Comment: Telnet has nothing to do with it. The DB2 process wasn't running.

Comment: What you mean is to test the port if it is open: telnet IPserver DB2port, telnet 192.168.0.1 50000

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, when I couldn't connect to my remote database with Data Studio Client and with DB2 CLP console. Make sure that you checked **ping** to your server and it is successful, you checked **dbm cfg** and you know **svcename**, **tcpip port number**, you checked ..System32\drivers\etc\services file and there is "*svcename*    *tcpip_port_number*/tcp" in that file.  So, while you get message in your db2diag.log ""TCPIP" protocol support was successfully started.", it isn't network problem. I opened ports on my server mashine: DB2 server tcpip port(svcename) and DB2 DAS tcpip port through the Firewall settings. I found help on this reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/configure-a-firewall-for-report-server-access?view=sql-server-ver16.
Be careful and consult with your system admin about security.

(*Sorry for my English*)))