# Issue with Hikari Pool and Jboss DB2 Connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, db2, hikaricp

I have a Spring Boot application which uses the Hikari Pool for DB2 connection. This application is deployed using Jboss.

When I enabled the following log, I could see that there is no need for new connection, It is sufficient as below

```
23:09:07,246 INFO  [stdout] (HikariPool-3 housekeeper) 2024-02-08 23:09:07.246 | DEBUG | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool:421   | HikariPool-3 - Before cleanup stats (total=30, active=0, idle=30, waiting=0)
23:09:07,246 INFO  [stdout] (HikariPool-3 housekeeper) 2024-02-08 23:09:07.246 | DEBUG | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool:421   | HikariPool-3 - After cleanup  stats (total=30, active=0, idle=30, waiting=0)
23:09:07,246 INFO  [stdout] (HikariPool-3 housekeeper) 2024-02-08 23:09:07.246 | DEBUG | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool:518   | HikariPool-3 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
```

Basically If there is no new connection needed, after 20 seconds, I get this WARNING, May I know why I get this warning and how to rectify it

```
23:09:20,158 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory] (HikariPool-1 connection adder) IJ030027: Destroying connection that is not valid, due to the following exception: com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b@28052227: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.31.10] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream, 
or socket output stream.  Error location: Reply.fill() - socketInputStream.read (-1).  Message: Read timed out. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:338)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.a(a.java:573)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.a(a.java:557)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.a(a.java:552)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.b(a.java:1709)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.y.b(y.java:264)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.y.c(y.java:342)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.y.c(y.java:455)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.y.v(y.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.b(ab.java:93)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.a(p.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.av.i(av.java:150)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k_.al(k_.java:2223)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k_.a(k_.java:3351)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k_.e(k_.java:1135)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.k_.execute(k_.java:1114)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.db2.DB2ValidConnectionChecker.isValidConnection(DB2ValidConnectionChecker.java:65)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.isValidConnection(BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.java:1372)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.getInvalidConnections(BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.java:1179)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:382)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:640)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:605)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:440)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:726)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:712)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:464)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:68)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$300(SSLSocketImpl.java:73)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:957)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.y.b(y.java:230)
    ... 31 more
```

**Pool configuration :**

```
connection-timeout=180000
minimum-idle=30
maximum-pool-size=700
idle-timeout=120000
max-lifetime=300000
auto-commit=true
leak-detection-threshold=180000

Hikari Version - 4.0.3
```

Comment: What's the pool configuration? Version of drivers and Hikari?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DB2 jdbc connection error Connection refused. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289409/db2-jdbc-connection-error-connection-refused-errorcode-4499-sqlstate-08001)

Comment: The whole point of Spring Boot is to deploy by itself, outside an app server. If you want to deploy into JBoss, then use plain Spring instead. To run it in JBoss you need to tweak your app "unnaturally". Dump JBoss.

Comment: @aled, please find the details added to the question. Actually my application is working fine. There is no issue in the application. I could see this WARNING only in the application logs and need to understand more on this. Could you help me with this. Also the link which you send is due to the connection refused error but I am getting read time out error.

Comment: @TheImpaler, my application in whole is running properly, If you know, please let me the reason for the WARN in the logs

Comment: It is a networking timeout issue: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/faq-jdbc-errorcode-4499-connectivity

Comment: A read-timeout can happen if a connection gets terminated by the other side (for any reason) . You can monitor to see the frequency this happens. The Db2-server side detailed diagnostics logs are also able to show connection terminations.  The connection pool software will just try to use a different connection next time one is required, which will either succeed or fail.